# Turning on delay of superfish menu

Tags: navigation

For some reason I cannot find the settings to turn on the delay for my superfish menu. I was able to get to it a couple of weeks, but not any more.

All I see when I go to /admin/config/user-interface/superfish is the ability to change the number of blocks and paths to superfish library.

How do I get to the settings where I can turn on delay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The settings for the menu is on the same page as the menu block settings page. You'll find your menu block at `/admin/structure/block` where you click `configure` for your menu block, and you'll be able to change the settings.